# scanimage: unrecognized option

Tags: sane, brother

I want to scan a page with *scanimage* and my Brother ADS-1700W scanner. The command I came up with looks like this:

```
scanimage -d "brother5:bus3;dev2" --mode "Black & White" --resolution 300 --AutoDescew=yes --format tiff  >out.tiff
```

This yields the following error:

```
unrecognized option '--AutoDescew'
```

The AutoDescew-option seems to be supported by my scanner. I checked this by executing

```
scanimage -h
```

which gave me the following output:

```
Options specific to device `brother5:bus3;dev2':   :

     --mode 24bit Color[Fast]|Black & White|True Gray|Gray[Error Diffusion] [24bit Color[Fast]]
         Select the scan mode
     --resolution 100|150|200|300|400|600|1200dpi [100]
         Sets the resolution of the scanned image.
     --source Automatic Document Feeder(left aligned)|Automatic Document Feeder(center aligned)|Automatic Document Feeder(left
 aligned,Duplex)|Automatic Document Feeder(center aligned,Duplex)|Card
 Slot|Card Slot(Duplex) [Automatic Document Feeder(left aligned)]
         Selects the scan source (such as a document-feeder).
     --brightness -50..50% (in steps of 1) [inactive]
         Controls the brightness of the acquired image.
     --contrast -50..50% (in steps of 1) [inactive]
         Controls the contrast of the acquired image.
     --MultifeedDetection[=(yes|no)] [inactive]
         
     --AutoDocumentSize[=(yes|no)] [no] [advanced]
         
     --AutoDeskew[=(yes|no)] [no] [advanced]
         
     --SkipBlankPage[=(yes|no)] [inactive]
         
     --SkipBlankPageSensitivity 0..100% (in steps of 1) [inactive]
```

Why is that option "unrecognized"? Does it have to do with the option being marked as "advanced"?

Bonus question: how would I enable the "inactive" options? E.g. `SkipBlankPage`?
I know my scanner supports this, but I have no idea how to enable it...

Comment: "_how would I enable the "inactive" options?_" I would guess you need the ADF enabled. There's little point skipping a blank page if you're only doing manual side-at-a-time scans

Comment: When scanning, I set source to "Automatic Document Feeder(left
 aligned,Duplex)". Thus it scans multiple pages just fine. But I can't set the SkipBlankPage option, because its inactive.

Comment: That's good to know. Please add your description of this to your question, so that it's easy for everyone to see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is `--AutoDeskew`, you’re trying `--AutoDescew` (‘c’ instead of ‘k’).

Comment: Wow, how could I be so blind. Looked at this for an hour straight and could not find this obvious solution. Thanks!
Any idea on how to enable the "inactive" options though? Especially SkipBlankPage would be quite useful.

Comment: I don’t know off-hand; perhaps it depends on the source or some other setting.